# redirect user to homepage after session expired in angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, session, laravel-4

I have a two part application: site part for visitors and "secure" part for loged users. I make it in AngluarJs and Laravel. Site part start page is public/#/ (other pages is: public/#/about,public/#/contact,...) and the start page for secure pages is public/secure#/ (some other pages are like public/secure#/something1, public/secure#/something2,...).

When user login into page, he can go to secure area after click on link. Secure area has a different layout than site layout.

My problem is:

How to redirect user to start page of site part after him/her session expired or he/she clicks on logout. P.S. I put a "public" because site is still in localhost for development and that is a start page for laravel.

Comment: What is your authentication setup? Are you using Laravels `auth` filter?

Comment: Yes.  I use Auth and in angular use sessionStorage to save data in session(token). And if session expired all data from sessionStorage is desapire and I do not know hot to redirect user to correct page.

Comment: use a watcher to monitor the sessionStorage and then use $location.path() to redirect whenever your condition is met.

Comment: @OlatundeGaruba can you give an example of a watcher?  I'd like to try this